# Python how to use (variables inside function F1) inside function (F2 which is inside F1)

Tags: python, function, recursion, scope

```
def F1():
    myvar = 1
    myArrayVar = []

    def F2():
        global myvar, myArrayVar # this will be changed by F2()
        myvar = 2
        myArrayVar.append(myVar)
        print(myvar)
    F2()

F1()
```

So I have a function inside a function. Since F2() is recursive, I have to store variables outside.

In C I would separate both or pass pointers, in Java I would create objects. But is there anyway in Python that allows me to do this quickly without much changes? I don't want to use global variables, `myvar` needs to be kept within the context of `F1()`

Thank you.

Comment: Are you modifying `myvar` within `F2`?

Comment: yes. I will update the question a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nonlocal` variables:

```py
def F1():
    myvar = 1
    myArrayVar = []

    def F2():
        nonlocal myvar, myArrayVar  # this will be changed by F2()
        myvar = 2
        myArrayVar.append(myvar)

    F2()
    print(myvar)
    print(myArrayVar)

F1()
```

```
2
[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually only `myvar` needs to be declared a [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) variable here. `myArrayVar` is just a closure variable, since you don't rebind the name it needs no special treatment.

```
def F1():
    myvar = 1
    myArrayVar = []

    def F2():
        nonlocal myvar  # allows changes to myvar to be seen by the outer scope
        myvar = 2
        myArrayVar.append(myvar)
        print(myvar)
    F2()

F1()
```